# MiniProfiler for ignoring page request

Tags: miniprofiler

I am trying to ignore same request multiple times in miniprofiler and added this line of code inside Application_BeginRequest but seems this line of code not working.

MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths = new[] { "/Economics/ViewProfilingResults.aspx" };

Answer (score 0):

MiniProfiler.Settings.IgnoredPaths accepts url path and not the file path (*.aspx)

Please refer one link below for more options to exclude specific items.

[How to exclude a specific service from miniprofiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764563/how-to-exclude-a-specific-service-from-miniprofiler)